# equals implementation test coverage junit java

Tags: java, inheritance, junit, equals

I have the first couple if checks in this equals implementation tested in junit but I can't figure out how to get pas the second if check to the final return check. Can someone help me figure this out :) I'll post my two assertions that get me past the first couple if checks. (Laila is my dog an in the code is a Pet object :)).

-- the code to test:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Pet pet = (Pet) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, pet.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.category, pet.category) &&
        Objects.equals(this.name, pet.name) &&
        Objects.equals(this.photoUrls, pet.photoUrls) &&
        Objects.equals(this.tags, pet.tags) &&
        Objects.equals(this.status, pet.status);
  }
```

These are the assertions I have that get me past the first two if checks:

```
        assertTrue(laila.equals(laila));
        assertFalse(laila.equals(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare with another `Pet` object that is not the same reference or `null`.

```
assertFalse(laila.equals(new Pet(/* instantiate different pet */)));
```